# Speeding Up MySQL Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, performance, performance-tuning

I am doing a complex full text search on a table with 130k+ records. It takes .5 seconds to complete. I was hoping it would be a bit faster.

Is there anything I can do to make it faster?

Below is the query along with explain + relevant tables

```
Query:

SELECT `phppos_items`.*, `phppos_categories`.`name` as category, `phppos_location_items`.`quantity` as quantity, `phppos_location_items`.`reorder_level` as location_reorder_level, `phppos_location_items`.`cost_price` as location_cost_price, `phppos_location_items`.`unit_price` as location_unit_price
FROM (`phppos_items`)
LEFT JOIN `phppos_categories` ON `phppos_categories`.`id` = `phppos_items`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_items` ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` and location_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `phppos_additional_item_numbers` ON `phppos_additional_item_numbers`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id`
LEFT JOIN `phppos_items_tags` ON `phppos_items_tags`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id`
LEFT JOIN `phppos_tags` ON `phppos_tags`.`id` = `phppos_items_tags`.`tag_id`
WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppos_items.item_number, product_id, description) AGAINST ('test') 
or MATCH(phppos_tags.name) AGAINST ('test') or 
MATCH(phppos_categories.name) AGAINST ('test') or 
MATCH(phppos_additional_item_numbers.item_number) AGAINST ('test'))and phppos_items.deleted=0
LIMIT 20 

EXPLAIN:

| id | select_type | table                          | type   | possible_keys                        | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items                   | ref    | deleted                              | deleted | 4       | const                          | 66679 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_categories              | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | pos.phppos_items.category_id   |     1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_location_items          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_location_items_ibfk_2 | PRIMARY | 8       | const,pos.phppos_items.item_id |     1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_additional_item_numbers | ref    | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | pos.phppos_items.item_id       |     1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items_tags              | ref    | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | pos.phppos_items.item_id       |     1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_tags                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | pos.phppos_items_tags.tag_id   |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show create table phppos_items;
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_items | CREATE TABLE `phppos_items` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tax_included` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `promo_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reorder_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expire` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `allow_alt_description` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_serialized` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_default_tax` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_service` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `commission_percent` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `commission_fixed` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_1` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_2` (`image_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_3` (`category_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_search` (`name`,`item_number`,`product_id`,`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_search` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `item_number_search` (`item_number`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `product_id_search` (`product_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description_search` (`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `size_search` (`size`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_suppliers` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_app_files` (`file_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133095 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table phppos_categories;
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_categories | CREATE TABLE `phppos_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `parent_id_name_index` (`parent_id`,`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_search` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table phppos_location_items;
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_location_items | CREATE TABLE `phppos_location_items` (
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cost_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `reorder_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_default_tax` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`,`item_id`),
  KEY `phppos_location_items_ibfk_2` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_location_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_locations` (`location_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_location_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show create table phppos_additional_item_numbers;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_additional_item_numbers | CREATE TABLE `phppos_additional_item_numbers` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`item_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `item_number_search` (`item_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_additional_item_numbers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table phppos_items_tags;
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_items_tags | CREATE TABLE `phppos_items_tags` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_2` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_tags` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show create table phppos_tags;
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_tags | CREATE TABLE `phppos_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag_name` (`name`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_search` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer rarely does anything useful `OR` constructs.

What you can attempt to do is

1. Get `ids` from each of the `MATCHs`
2. `UNION` the results
3. `JOIN` back to the necessary tables to get the desired field.

Something like this:

```
SELECT i2.*, c2.name AS category, ...
    FROM (
       SELECT i.id
           FROM phppos_items AS i
           WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)
       UNION DISTINCT
       SELECT i.id
           FROM phppos_items AS i
           JOIN phppos_categories AS c  ON c.id = i.category_id
           WHERE MATCH(c.name) AGAINST(...)
       UNION DISTINCT
       ...
        ) AS u
    JOIN phppos_items AS i2  ON i2.id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN phppos_categories AS c2  ON c2.id = i.category_id
    ... ;
```

To further explain:

- Each `SELECT` in the `UNION` should efficiently use the `FULLTEXT` index.
- `UNION DISTINCT` will eliminate any dups.
- `AND deleted=0` could be added to each subquery or wait until the outer query.
- Since the `JOINs` are 'running the opposite direction', you may need to add indexes such as `i.category_id`.  (I did not check.)
- Each inner `SELECT` will (hopefully) have very few (or zero) ids
- The `UNION` will have a small number of ids.
- The final set of `JOINs` will work on only on that small number, not all 66679; this is where the speedup will occur.
- The total time is likely to be less, in spite of the complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got rid of the OR's (Just searched less fields) and this got the search down to 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to  reduce the amount of occurrences in the inner query over `phppos_items`. A way to do that is to get only the heavier records using a subquery. I see that you are using `LIMIT 20`, so I assume that you need online 20 records from the overall. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

What you can do to do so, is to trim the working set using a condition over the match score. i.e.:

`WHERE [...]
  (MATCH(phppos_tags.name) AGAINST ('test')) > 0.65`

Comment: What do you mean by heavier records?

Comment: @ChrisMuench `MATCH ... AGAINST` has something of a double role.  In addition to being a search operator, if you evaluate it as an expression in a numeric context , it returns a relevance score for each row.  If instead of relevance, we call that value "weight," then "heavier" must mean "more relevant."  Hence `ORDER BY (MATCH (...) AGAINST (...))`.

Comment: @ChrisMuench as Michael pointed, I meant "relevance". Also, this query is over test data, which could not be representing a real case. I suggest you to create a sample working set closer as possible  from your expected production environment.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL FT search isn't that fast as we hope to be.

I'd recommend Sphinx - http://sphinxsearch.com/ - it provides fast and relevant full-text search.

If you are wondering how fast is Sphinx (from my experience), it can take few minutes to search 200M records with MySQL, but with Sphinx, less than 2 seconds, and better accuracy.

Comment: Wish I had the option. My software is installed on shared hosts and don't have access to this.